# using conditions on populate with waterline and sails.js

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to use conditions on populate, but can't solve it.
The following code exists and working great, just add conditions made it crash.

```
Page.find({ 'id' : id })
.populate('addons', { 'type' : 'seo' })
.then(function(page)) {

});
```

but when i try to add 'or' condition it crashes.

```
Page.find({ 'id' : id })
.populate('addons', { 
    or: [
        {
            'type' : 'seo'
        },
        {
            'type' : 'general'
        },
        {
            'type' : 'local',
            'zone' : zoneId // zoneId holds the correct information
        }
    ]
})
.then(function(page)) {

});
```

thanks.

Comment: An error message would be really helpful.

Comment: the server crashes.. nothing specific.. am i writing it the right way?

Comment: There has to be an error message when it crashes... how can we help you pinpoint the error without any details about what the server is complaining about? That code looks fine and works when I put it into my project. Post the error message for help.

Comment: Thanks guys, i found the problem which didn't relate to the actuall "or" condition, but was to the mysql table structure that the model created. I'm trying to do one of the following now, searching for null fields, or define columns not null (notNull=true didn't work). thank you!